# How to make the link inside Button change color on hover without hovering over link

Tags: html, css

**My link changes color on hovering over it directly but does not change color when I hover over the button and not the link directly**

```
btn:hover{
color: black;
}
```

This does not work.

```
a:hover{
color:black
}
```

This is working currently but does not do the job as needed.

[image: When the cursor is over the Button but not the link direcly]

[image: When the cursor is over the link directly.]

**How do I make the button change the color of the link when I hover over it? 
As seen in the first image.**

Comment: what you mean btn selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you didn't add padding to the `<a>` tag. it need to add padding or width to define a area to hover over. if you add padding in parent `<li>`, therefore you need to hover over the `<li>` to change the color of the `<a>` tag.

```css
.nav{overflow:hidden}
.nav ul{list-style:none; text-align:center;}
.nav ul li{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top}
.nav ul li a{display:block; padding:10px 20px; background-color: silver; color: black}
.nav ul li a:hover{background-color: darkgrey; color: white}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#!">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

btn is wrong try button selector like below.

```css
button:hover{
color: black;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if I put the class name or selector name. It works the same.

Comment: would you please put your html here too?

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}
.btn{
background-color:black;}
.btn:hover {background: gray;}
.btn:hover > a {color:black}
```

```html
<button class="btn"><a href="#">Home</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

```
btn:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: This changes the color of the link but the button does not change the color to white completely. The button does not change to white completely on hover.

Comment: btn:hover {background-color: #ffffff;}

btn:hover a {
  color: black;
}

Answer (score 0):

btn is not an element so if it is a class you have to use .btn:hover else you have to use button:hover

The problem is, that your link doesn't fill the whole btn.
You have to use btn:hover but the color should change only on the link:

```
.btn:hover > a{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this but it doesn't work. The link does not change color at all.

Comment: Can you please show us the html and css code you already have? Otherwise we can't understand your exact question.

Comment: Got the answer. I had to change the dimensions of the link to fill the button.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have few ways to do it.
Here are two examples, the one that you should probably use because you need to expand link dimensions because of the false click,and second is how you did it probably.

```
.btn:hover a{
  color:black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zmirko/rf473kbs/15/

Answer (score 0):

//Using plain JavaScript with out CSS

```
<head>  

    <title>  

        How to change the background color 

        after clicking the button ? 

    </title> 

</head>  



<body style = "text-align:center;"> 



    <h1 style = "color:green;" >  

        GeeksForGeeks  

    </h1>  



    <p id = "GFG_UP" style = 

        "font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">      

    </p> 



    <button onclick = "gfg_Run()">  

        Click here 

    </button> 



    <p id = "GFG_DOWN" style = 

        "color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"> 

    </p> 



    <script> 

        var el_up = document.getElementById("GFG_UP"); 

        var el_down = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN"); 

        var str = "Click on button to change the background color"; 



        el_up.innerHTML = str; 



        function changeColor(color) { 

            document.body.style.background = color; 

        } 



        function gfg_Run() { 

            changeColor('yellow'); 

            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed"; 

        }          

    </script>  

</body>
```